# How to refresh multiple line SWT label?

Tags: java, swt

I am trying to update a lable with contents that should take multiple lines. What I observe is that only the first line is shown and the rest of the new content is not displayed.

`layout()` on the parent composite doesn't help. What helps is setting the initial content for the label large enough so that it takes the needed number of lines.

My question is - how do I update the text of the label so that it takes exactly the number of lines needed to display the new content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `grabExcessVerticalSpace` to `true` on the parent solves the problem.